CIFS in docker-compose file
I'm trying to mount my internal samba directory in docker-compose volume, it partially works. For example when i execute

docker exec -it <airflow-webserver-1> /bin/bash
opt/airflow/sftp ls

It returns the folder residing there. Means the directory got mounted successfully but when I further try to access any folder inside it says permission deneid.
I have tried adding forceuid,forcegid,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 and directory related uid and gid as well, but nothing worked for me.
example of my code given below:
volumes: postgres-db-volume: cifs-sftp-volume: driver: local driver_opts: type: cifs device: //<ip>/folder o: username=,password=,forceuid,forcegid,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,sec=ntlmssp,nounix,vers=3.0 
If anyone has experience this please provide your valuable suggestion.
